# Mysql duplicate table with insert throws error when using wildcard

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have one table that I need to duplicate the data but I need to exlude just one column.

I'm trying :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM hex_articles;
ALTER TABLE tmp DROP COLUMN art;
INSERT pim_articles SELECT * FROM tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

But I'm getting the next error

## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

The insert works if I declare the columns like this;

```
INSERT pim_articles (dos) SELECT dos FROM tmp;
```

Whe whit ***** the insert is not working

Comment: Do you create pim_articles elsewhere? And what does it look like?

Comment: `INSERT pim_articles SELECT * FROM tmp;` <-- I'm not familiar with this syntax.  What does it do?  Does it even run?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen  yes it does as long as pim articles exists and has the same columns as tmp

Comment: `SELECT *` is generally an evil thing, for reasons such as what you are seeing right now.  You may not know which or how many columns are being selected.  In order for that insert to work, the numbers (and possibly type) of _all_ columns would have to match exactly in both tables.  Your second version, which lists out all columns, is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Ok, I see, the only change made on the data base is the column art that in the original table was a simple column and in the second table the art column is associated with a foreign key

Comment: So you are saying that pim_articles has more columns than temp - ie what the error message is telling you?

Comment: Yes pim has 1 extra column. Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1... I was hoping to find a solution for the insert but ignore the column 'art'